# How to get a video poster’s image dimensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, html5-video

How to get the image dimensions (width and height) of the `poster` image in a `<video poster="…">` element? jQuery is acceptable.

Comment: Note that before the video resource is loaded, and after the poster has loaded, the video's intrinsic width and height are the ones of the poster image. This means you could actually get this poster image size by checking the offsetWidth and offsetHeight of your video after your reset it's src to `''`, but you'd also need to be sure no css is applied on it...

Answer (score 2):

If your `<video>` element is referenced as `yourVideo` (e.g. `const yourVideo = document.querySelector("video");`), then you can get its `poster` URL by the `poster` property. This is just an image URL, so get its dimensions like with any image URL:

```
const poster = Object.assign(new Image(), {
    src: yourVideo.poster
  });

poster.addEventListener("load", () => console.log(poster.width, poster.height));
```

Comment: Feels the need to nit-pick here... What if the url points to a server script that returns a different randomly sized image at every request?

Comment: @Kaiido Well, then it’s impossible since there’s no property that holds the poster image as an actual `HTMLImageElement`, `ImageData` or something similar. But I think it’s also impossible to guarantee a result that is always correct in _every conceivable_ scenario.

Comment: Yes, the point is that there is no API to even know if the poster image did load. Your solution exposed as obvious is actually just a workaround to this lack of a proper API.